# Detect region based on geo location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, location, geo

I have a json file with lists of regions.

Each region has geo border points like:

```
id": "4650d7cc-b834-4ed4-a139-40f5037711fc",
"name": "region 1",
"coords": [
    [
        [4.74, 52.431],
        [4.781, 52.426],
        [4.831, 52.42],
        [4.855, 52.417],
        [4.862, 52.422],
        [4.861, 52.425],
        [4.866, 52.428], ...
```

How can I detect region based on some location using js, C# or any google service?

Comment: By using `coords` Eg. [4.74, 52.431] ?

Comment: @Pugazh, yes. By using lat and lng.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `containsLocation` method from the [Google Maps JavaScript API Geometry Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry). From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly):

> **containsLocation(point:LatLng, polygon:Polygon)**
>
> Return Value:  boolean
>
> Computes whether the given point lies inside the specified polygon.